# Animations won't transfer states until entire animation is completed

Tags: animation, state, unity

I am following the [survival shooter tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/player-character) and am using Unity 5.

I just completed this video (linked) and I tested played it to see my animations worked but it seems like it will only transition from idle to walking after the entirety of the idle animation completes. The idle animation is quite long so my character will move around when it looks like its idling since the movement responds right away.

Did I mess up something in my transitions? I followed the directions exactly and didn't change anything in the inspector that I wasn't told to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue. I needed to un-check the "Has Exit Time" option in the state transition line's properties.

Comment: Thanks for finding this out! In Unity 5.2.0f3, I'm seeing that you specifically need to uncheck it for the transition from Idle to Move. When I uncheck Has Exit Time for the Move to Idle transition, it still doesn't work, but you can uncheck it for just Idle to Move, or both. Now, if I could only fix the lighting...